# Why do lips heal fast

Tags: human-biology

Whenever I have any cut in my lips ,it gets healed in 2-3 days so why do lips get healed faster as compared to other body parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3842869/):

> Wet or moist wound treatment significantly reduces the time required for re-epithelialization

Since the lips are (normally) constantly being moistened by saliva, this could be the reason you experience accelerated cut healing.